# Mobile Identification in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, mobile-devices

I am looking to identify not only the user agent, but phone capabilities within Tomcat 6.0.26.

Is there anything like the Apache Mobile Filter for Tomcat.  I am after something that will check against a regularly updated repository for the capabilities of modern handsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Mobile Filter is possible to use with tomcat, if you use Apache as webserver and mod_jk as connector.

The configuration is very easy in httpd.conf set this parameter:

```
JkEnvVar AMF_MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT undefined
```

and in your java pages to retrieve the same capability:

```
request.getAttribute("AMF_MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT")
```

for other information look the wiki page:

http://wiki.apachemobilefilter.org